# required most recent date for the value in Column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':['a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c'],
                  'Col2':[ '2020-12-01','2020-11-05','2019-01-05','2017-08-07',
                          '2018-07-16','2018-12-31','2019-11-30','2018-05-15',
                          '2019-01-15']})
```

I want the unique values in Col1 to be with most recent date Col2.
The required column would be like this

```
    Col1  Col2 
0   a     2020-12-01
1   b     2018-12-31
2   c     2019-11-30
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, convert `Col2` as `datetime` using `pd.to_datetime` if it's not datetime already, then use `GroupBy.max`

```
df['Col2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Col2'])
df.groupby('Col1').max()

#            Col2
# Col1
# a    2020-12-01
# b    2018-12-31
# c    2019-11-30
```

Answer (score 2):

Sort the dataframe based on `Col2` first and then `groupby` and agg `last`

Do:

```
df.sort_values(by='Col2').groupby('Col1').last()
```